# How to get response of a nested api call using RxSwift and alamofire?

Tags: alamofire, rx-swift, rxalamofire

How to get response of a nested api call using RxSwift and alamofire? Here i get a response from an alamofire api cal and with that result i need to call another api call. I want to get the second api call response. Can anyone suggest me a solution to solve this. please.

```
func origin() -> Observable<String> {
return Alamofire.request("httpbin.org/get").rx.responseJSON()
```

}

```
func otherApiCall(with origin: String) -> Observable<YourType> {
// Other api call using origin
return Alamofire...........
```

}

> then

```
origin()
.flatMap{ origin in 
    otherApiCall(with: origin)  
}
.subscribe(onNext: { response in 

})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: "Here I get a response" - where?

Comment: From the first api call. i will get a response, by using that response i want to call the second api call

Comment: That was a hint to you that you should post some code.

Comment: Here i put some sample code. please check it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not explaining much but as per my understanding if you want to call api using other api's response than below code should work.

```
func firstRequest() -> Observable<firstRequestResponseType> {
    return firstRequest
}

firstRequest
.flatMap { (firstRequestResponseType) ->  Observable<secondRequestResponseType>
    return secondRequest
}
.map { (secondRequestResponseType)
 //you can user second request’s response here
}
.subscribe()
```

Comment: Actually the compiler didnt wait for the response of second call response

Comment: @gunjan you will reach in map block after both API request will get  complete

Comment: actually the second api call depends upon a value from the response of first api call. And here i need to call the second api call with those first response values that satisfies the condition. So the second api call will be called any number of times .And i need to get the response to append with the first response in a looping manner..can you help me

Comment: you can use first request's response in flatMap block {in above example} or if you want to share first request's response multiple times you can use share() method of RxSwift